# SF Agile Accelerator LEX

Tags: lightning-experience, ui

Has anyone ever experienced the dragging of tasks or work in the Work Manager becoming disabled?

Answer (score 0):

"Hello Agile Accelerator users, we will updating all production orgs to the latest version 1.123 on Monday Oct 28. This will include the new Sprint Board and the fix for the issue with dragging and dropping Tasks on the Sprint Wall."